# SCSS extends from class which generated by loop

Tags: css, sass

I want to extend class, but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

```
$border: "#e0e0e0";

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .p#{$i} {
    padding: ($i*5)px;
  }
}

.bw{
  @extend .p4;

  background: #fff;
  border:1px solid $border;
}
```

Comment: The reason you don't see it working is possibly because of `padding: ($i*5)px;`. This would produce output like `padding: 5 px` (note the space) instead of as `padding: 5px;`. You should instead write it as `padding: ($i*5) * 1px;`.

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood your question correctly, your code is actually correct :).

I've simplified your code slightly to help it be more obvious that the class is extended, I think because there is so many classes being produced you may not have seen that the output has added your `.bw` class to the `.p4` class.

Hopefully my simplified version will help you understand a little more how SASS extends work.

[Play with this gist on SassMeister.](http://sassmeister.com/gist/354f74fb5563ace442be12123602be54)

Answer (score 0):

@Harry you were right, I changed `padding: ($i*5)px;` to `padding: ($i*5) * 1px;`

and it worked. Thanks